# JQuery Sticky Headers with Dynamic Content Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

Stuck on this issue for the past few days. Thought I tried everything. Hope I can get some relief from someone.

Sticky headers work if the content is static. Headers roll display and rollout of view when another category is in view. The problem occurs when there is dynamic data that is loaded with JQuery in the HTML. At that point, sticky headers still uses the old position of previous headers and displays the sticky headers.

So instead of display a sticky header in a new position of a category since the previous category was expanded, the sticky header is displayed in old position as if the category was not expanded, thus creating an unwanted effect.

Thinking the solution would be easy enough as identifying and capturing the new position of the followmebar class and displaying the sticky headers properly.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I have sticky headers using JQuery code:

```
var stickyHeaders =  function() {

                     console.log("enter stickyHeaders")

      var $window = $(window),
          $stickies;

      var load = function(stickies) {

        console.log("enter stickies")



            //});

        if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

          $stickies = stickies.each(function() {

            //console.log(stickies);

            var $thisSticky = $(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');


            $thisSticky
                .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
                .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight())
                  .parent()
                  .height($thisSticky.outerHeight());   


          });




        }

         $window.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function() {

              _whenScrolling();     
          });
      };

      var _whenScrolling = function() {

        console.log("enter _whenScrolling")

        $stickies.each(function(i) {            

          var $thisSticky = $(this),
              $stickyPosition = $thisSticky.data('originalPosition');

          if ($stickyPosition <= $window.scrollTop()) {        

            var $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(i + 1),
                $nextStickyPosition = $nextSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight');

            $thisSticky.addClass("fixed").addClass('show-followMeBar').removeClass('hide-followMeBar');

            if ($nextSticky.length > 0 && $thisSticky.offset().top >= $nextStickyPosition) {

              $thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", $nextStickyPosition);
            }

          } else {

            var $prevSticky = $stickies.eq(i - 1);

            $thisSticky.removeClass("fixed").addClass('hide-followMeBar').removeClass('show-followMeBar');

            if ($prevSticky.length > 0 && $window.scrollTop() <= $thisSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight')) {

              $prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
            }
          }
        });
      };

      return {
        load: load
      };

    }();

    $(function() {


                stickyHeaders.load($(".followMeBar"));  




    });
```

and CSS:

```
.show-followMeBar{
            display: block;

        }
        .hide-followMeBar{
            display: none;

        }
        .followMeBar {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -999;
  /*color: #fff*/;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
.followMeBar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}
.followMeBar.fixed.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

and HTML:

```
  <div class="followMeBar">
                              One
   </div>

   <div class=" slider single-item division" id="d1">   

    <div class="slick-active">  

        <span class="">One | 13/14</span>
    </div>

    <!--Dynamic Content goes here-->
</div>

<div class="followMeBar">
                        Two
</div>

<div class=" slider single-item division" id="d1">  

    <div class="slick-active">  

        <span class="">Two | 13/14</span>
    </div>

    <!--Dynamic Content goes here-->
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle

Comment: This is actually a working solution. After making so many adjustments, my refresh no longer refreshed. I had to use a different machine to test. Thanks for your help @Steve

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.followMeBar').css('transform','none');
$('.followMeBar').removeData( "originalPosition" );
$('.followMeBar').removeData( "originalHeight" );
$(window).scrollTop(0);
stickyHeaders.load($(".followMeBar"));
```